# flat data Hierarchical order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

any idea about ordering this flat data to below order ?

this simple query is not working

```
select QuestionID , QuestionText , ReferenceID , ParentQuestionID from Question
where ReferenceID = 10208
order by ParentQuestionID,QuestionID
```

flat data

[image]

this should be order like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the hierarchy string then sort it. For storage you can use [hierarchyid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx)

```
WITH Question AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (10208, -1), 
        (10209, 10208), 
        (10211, 10208), 
        (10214, 10208),
        (10212, 10209),
        (10213, 10209),
        (10215, 10212)
    ) Question(QuestionID, ParentQuestionID)
), cte AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT *, 0 AS Level, CAST('/' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar) + '/' AS varchar(100)) AS Hierarchy 
    FROM Question WHERE ParentQuestionID = -1
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive part
    SELECT q.*, Level + 1, CAST(Hierarchy + CAST(q.QuestionID AS varchar) + '/' AS varchar(100)) 
    FROM Question q INNER JOIN cte ON q.ParentQuestionID = cte.QuestionID
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY Hierarchy
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7d/591)

**EDIT**

To order by descending

```
WITH Question AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (10208, -1), 
        (10209, 10208), 
        (10211, 10208), 
        (10214, 10208),
        (10212, 10209),
        (10213, 10209),
        (10215, 10212)
    ) Question(QuestionID, ParentQuestionID)
), cte AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT *, 0 AS Level, CAST('/' + CAST(QuestionID AS varchar(max)) + '/' AS varchar(max)) AS Hierarchy 
    FROM Question WHERE ParentQuestionID = -1
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive part
    SELECT q.*, Level + 1, CAST(cte.Hierarchy + CAST(q.QuestionID AS varchar(max)) + '/' AS varchar(max)) 
    FROM Question q INNER JOIN cte ON q.ParentQuestionID = cte.QuestionID
), rn AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentQuestionID ORDER BY Hierarchy DESC) Seq FROM cte
)
SELECT * FROM rn ORDER BY ParentQuestionID, Seq
```

Comment: how can i order child question as descending order ?